# Angular Signals - computed signal based on input

Tags: angular-signals

I'm asking for opinions about my use-case.

very simplified example:

```js
@Input() parentComponent;
childSignal = computed(() => this.parentComponent.parentSignal());
```

This code will throw runtime error because `parentComponent` is undefined when signal gets computed for the first time.

Now what would be your way? Initializing signal in `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: Are you facing any issue when using the approach mentioned above?

Comment: This code will throw runtime error because parentComponent is undefined when signal gets computed for the first time.

Comment: Since computed signals "recovers" It should be fine i guess.this.parentComponent?.parentSignal()

Answer (score 1):

You can also define an alias setter for the input signal,e.g.

```js
readonly userIdSignal = signal(null);
@Input({alias: 'userIdSignal'})
set _userIdSignal(v: string) { this.userIdSignal.set(v) }
```

... and remove the alias setter once we have real signal inputs as @Simon_Weaver said.

### Update Angular v17.1 (EDIT 2024-01-24)

Signal-based component inputs are finally here! :-)

See e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1710-2024-01-17 and https://justangular.com/blog/signal-inputs-are-here-to-change-the-game

```js
  readonly userIdSignal = input<string|null>(null);
  // or
  readonly userIdSignal = input.required<string>('some default');
```

Answer (score 0):

We will eventually get `{ signal: true }` components that have real Signal inputs.

For now (until this feature exists) the simplest approach is to:

- Create a signal that is updated in `ngOnChanges`.

  ```
  @Input('userId')
  userId: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)
  {
     this.userIdSignal.set(this.userId); 
  }

  userIdSignal = signal(null);
  ```

Comment: Angular v17.1 release the input signals for components